# How to pipe response from request in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, request

So i use `request` library to get an URL. I would like to pipe it to a `response` in Express but I haven't figured it out how to do it.

```
function routeHandler(req, res) {
...
request.getAsync(theUrl)
    .spread(function(response,body) {
        // how to pipe it to res here?
    })
```

Comment: You mean to say you would like to associate the data from the request to the res object?

Comment: I would like to send the response from that url (an image) out; like a proxy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its's supported by request library. I should have read the documentation thoroughly.

```
var reply = request(actualUrl)
req.pipe(reply)
reply.pipe(res)
```

Comment: Hi my friend, I'm in the same issue. My question is: Where you can put the function `pipe` in `request.getAsync(theUrl).spread(function(response,body) {  })` ???

Comment: @robe007 i think you should not use getAsync in this case.